# Button in same line as input and label

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to put a button in the same line of label and input box.

I want that button adjust to content, so I don't need a big button. Even, if it could have an image, would be better.

This is my code now:

```
             <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                 <button onclick= "codeAddress();" style="float:left;">Buscar</button>
                 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="placeActivity">Lugar</label>
                    <input type="text" name="placeActivity" id="placeActivity" value="">
                 </div>
              </div>
```

And fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/3jgeop7t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JQuery Mobile Three-column grids](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/content/content-grids.html)

## [*DEMO:*](http://jsfiddle.net/3jgeop7t/10/)

```
<div class="ui-grid-b"  data-role="fieldcontain">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><button onclick= "codeAddress();" data-inline="true">Buscar</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><label for="placeActivity">Lugar</label></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c"><input type="text" name="placeActivity" id="placeActivity" value=""></div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

If you just want a normal button the use `data-inline="true"`
[image]

Update using css to fixe the label size:

```
.ui-grid-b[data-role=fieldcontain] label{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

## [*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/3jgeop7t/12/)

[image]

Comment: Text is too small comparing to button. Is it possible to put all to the same size?

Comment: Yes but first i have to know what you are using twitter boostrap, 960grids... font awesome?? or just wrap it in h4  `<h4 class="ui-title" tabindex="0" role="heading" aria-level="1"><label for="placeActivity">Lugar</label></h4>`

Comment: That was great. I was thinking in adding a "<br>" or something similar, but that is better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

If they won't fit, adjust the width of each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3jgeop7t/8/)**

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class='main'>
    <button onclick="codeAddress();">Buscar</button>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class='container'>
        <label for="placeActivity">Lugar</label>
        <input type="text" name="placeActivity" id="placeActivity" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    width:100%;
}
button {
    float:left;
    width:200px !important;
}
.container {
    float:right;
    width:50% !important;
    top:-60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use jQuery Mobile with special css. You need change same properties in inline style or in custom css file.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <button onclick= "codeAddress();" style="float:left; width:auto;">Buscar</button>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="clear: none; overflow: hidden;">
    <label for="placeActivity">Lugar</label>
    <input type="text" name="placeActivity" id="placeActivity" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```